# Extend the functionality of the print statement/function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, decorator

I want to print things to a certain specification, such as printing containers (`[]`, `{}`, `()`) using their `str()` method instead of `repr()`.  It's trivial to write a function that will do that

```
def str_print_list(alist):
    print "["+", ".join(map(str, alist))+"]"
```

but it'd be awfully nice if I could just extend or decorate either the [`print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) or the [`print()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) (in Python 2.7)

I could do something sort of like this, which works in python 3 (tested in Python 3.2.3 at http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python3_online.php)

```
class foo(): 
    def __str__(self):
        return "String"
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Repr"

print([foo()])

def my_decorator(func):
    def inner(alist):
        if isinstance(alist, list):
            return func("["+", ".join(map(str, alist))+"]")
        else:
            return func(alist)
    return inner

print = my_decorator(print)
print([foo()])
```

Which gives me an output of

```
[Repr]
[String]
```

but gives me a syntax error in python 2.7.6 at

```
print = my_decorator(print)
```

until I import

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

which makes sense, because statements can't (as far as I know) be decorated or reassigned.

So my question is

1. Is it possible to decorate the print statement so I don't have to import the function?
2. Is this even a good idea, or should I just be more explicit and use my `str_print_list()` function?  In this case I know *for a fact* that this would be for my personal use and would be used primarily for debugging

Comment: In Python 2.x `print` is not a function but a language construct. You need to perform `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2.x in order to get the Python 3.x style `print` function.

Comment: @isedev yeah, I say that in my question (towards the bottom).  I wanted to be clear that I'm asking for a way to extend the statement if possible, otherwise just the imported function

Comment: ok, let me put it another way: you can't decorate statements, so you have to import the function.

Comment: You can install a custom handler to `sys.stdout` that will intercept print calls, altering them before they are piped to stdout.  This works on all python versions.  An example is what I did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512442/python-coloring-regex-matches/25513389#25513389

Comment: @roippi so I'd just replace the `colorize` function with one that makes the lists cleaner and then toss in some if statements?

Comment: @roippi I implemented that but the thing that gets passed to the `write()` method isn't the actual list.  I don't always want `str()` to be called instead of `repr()`, just when I'm printing a list/dictionary/tuple/container

Comment: @Dannnno indeed, by the time it gets to `write` it is always stringified.  If you can't strictly string-manipulate the default representation then the `sys.stdout` approach isn't the best for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, statements can't be changed.
2. No. The way to handle this is to make your own `list` and pass that around -- this is exactly what inheritance is made for.

Like this:

```
class MyPrintableList(list):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "[{}]".format(",".join(self))

print MyPrintableList([foo()])
```